# Google PubSub Emulator - Maven Repo?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsub-emulator

Need to implement unit test cases for a custom component written on top of PubSub client API.

Is there a maven repo where I could get PubSub emulator jars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't currently distribute the emulator outside of gcloud (this may change in the future). For testing purposes, you could just use the version that gets installed by gcloud (e.g. vendor it into your version control).

Comment: Copying it over is a solution. Thank you.